# How to phrase the following sentence of cause and effect relationship?

Tags: indefinite-article, logic, parallelism

How to phrase the following sentence of cause and effect relationship?

I tried to phrase sentence, but because I'm not English native speaker, and this is the first time that I build a sentence like this, so I would like to get a feedback about it. Here is the build sentence:

> Since it doesn’t have nucleus, it also doesn’t have nucleolus

I want to say that because prokaryotic cell doesn't have nucleus, so it also doesn't have nucleolus. They always go together since the nucleolus is sub-part of nucleus.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Almost correct, but you should add "a" before nucleus and nucleolus and delete also if you want it more natural.

Comment: *Because* works just as well as *since*.